Receiving a 200 response code, but the data is not updating?
I want to load test for registration with One Time Password (OTP), so I have used 2 .csv files for registration and OTP by using parameters, and also separately used an API collection for those two.
After running it, the response is 200 ok. The reflection is getting in dashboard alone in admin site, but not getting data in the customer module?

I've updated your question by correcting some grammar and improving readability to (hopefully) get you some more answers. However, please feel free to revert my changes if you disagree with them at all.

okay! too short..no problem..thks dvniel

HTTP Status Code 200 doesn't necessarily mean that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing. It's just a HTTP protocol level status code which means that there were no client or server errors or redirects.
You might want to add i.e. View Results Tree listener and inspect response details, most probably something is wrong and i.e. you're hitting the login page instead of submitting the data.
In order to protect yourself from this kind of false-positive results you can add i.e. Response Assertion and define custom pass/fail criteria to ensure that response contains the anticipated data or on the other hand doesn't contain any warnings or errors.

thks for your suggesstion ivan
